# Splitting DataFrame into two DataFrames and filter these two DataFrames in order to have the same dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following problem and had an idea to solve it, but it didn't worked:
I have the data on DAX Call and Put Options for *every trading day in a month*. After transforming and some calculations I have the following DataFrame:
[DaxOpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDBhp.png). The goal is now to get rid of every row (either Call or Put Option) which does not have the respective pair. With pair I mean a Call and Put Option with the same 'EXERCISE_PRICE' and 'TAU', where 'TAU' = the time to maturity in years. The red boxes in the picture are examples for a pair. So either having a DataFrame with only the pairs or having two DataFrames with Call and Put Options where the rows are the respective pairs.

My idea was creating two new DataFrames one which contains only the Call Options and the other the Put Options, sort them after 'TAU' and 'EXERCISE_PRICE' and working my way through with pandas isin function, in order to get rid of the Call or Put Options which do not have the respective pair.

DaxOptCall = DaxOpt[DaxOpt.CALL_PUT_FLAG == 'C']

DaxOptPut = DaxOpt[DaxOpt.CALL_PUT_FLAG == 'P']

The problem is that the DaxOptCall and DaxOptPut have different dimensions, so isin function is not applicable. I am trying to find the most efficient way, since the data I am using now is just a fraction from the real data.

Would appreciate any help or idea.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you:

Once you separated your df into two dfs by CALL/PUT options, convert the column(s) that are unique to your pairs into index columns:

```
# Assuming your unique columns are TAU and EXERCISE_PRICE
df_call = df_call.set_index(["EXERCISE_PRICE", "TAU"])
df_put = df_put.set_index(["EXERCISE_PRICE", "TAU"])
```

Next, take the intersection of the indexes, which will return a pandas MultiIndex object

```
mtx = df_call.index.intersection(df_put.index)
```

Then use the mtx object to extract the common elements from the dfs

```
df_call.loc[mtx]
df_put.loc[mtx]
```

You can merge these if you want them to be in the same df and reset the index to the original column.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replay. Sadly it does not work, nonetheless it is good to know for me. The problem is that the columns "EXERCISE_PRICE" and "TAU" are not unique, but their combination is unique. The consequence is that the Multindex object has much more EXERCISE_PRICES than TAUS and the final dfs are empty. Is there another way?

Comment: is it producing an error or not resulting in the desired output?

Comment: It is not resulting in the desired output, because the output is empty.

Comment: If you want me to help you, please be more clear of what you are getting exactly. Which output are we talking about? Is mtx empty or not?

Comment: Sorry I edited my first comment and thought you saw it. So using your notation from above df_call.loc[mtx] and df_put.loc[mtx] are empty. In my opinion the reason for that is because the columns EXERCISE_PRICE and TAU are not unique which results in mtx having more EXERCISE_PRICES than TAUS.

Comment: Okay, try it now. I made a mistake by assuming set_index was in place by default, and so I corrected my answer.

Comment: Hi is it possible to get the EXERCISE_PRICE and TAU out of the Index from df_call and df_put and place them back into the dfs like it was in the df DaxOpt?

Comment: yes. try this: df_new = df.reset_index(). this will take everything out of the index. You can also set different columns as index by using df.set_index() in the same manner as it is shown in my answer.